# can users follow specific Django model IDs

Tags: getstream-io

I'm quite new to GetStream. After successfully testing/using the default feeds, now I would need that users could choose within one Django Model several records to follow, e.g. user1 follows Model IDs=1,10,20 updates; user2 follows model IDs=1,30,40 updates and so on.

A Celery task can update Model records and users that are following specific IDs should get a notification if the records were updated.

Is it possible? 
If so how? I sincerely don't have a clue how to do it.

A huge thanks GetStream for all great resources!

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some code in the Django SDK called `feed_manager.get_notification_feed()` which can get a notification feed name for users based on an activity type. Our README file talks about doing this in a `Tweet` model [here](https://github.com/getstream/stream-django#notification-feed). You might need to adapt some code to your specific use case.

Our Python SDK has a function for building a batch of follow requests to help manage `user:1 follows model:1, user:1 follows model:10` and so on; check out the follow_many code [here](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-python/blob/e0c2c298cff2452d566a24616ebedf87a636ba25/stream/tests.py#L813-L829).

Comment: Thanks Ian! Thanks to all the Team!